# css border hack for 2 column div template

Tags: html, css

2 border will overlap and produced bad looking. I want to apply border to my li which located in a div, that also need to use border to seperate itself from the beside div,

```
<div id="1">

</div>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

look at my demo http://jsfiddle.net/CfYhY/

my desire effect :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOA78.jpg

Comment: use negative margin: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CfYhY/7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried using negative margins?

http://jsfiddle.net/CfYhY/1/

```
li {
    border-left: 4px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

btw, you should not start element id with a number.